# Round of 16 champions league

Tags: football, champions-league

How will the round of 16 draw work. 1 pot group winners, 1 pot runners up, yet Liverpool can't play PSG or Man City so what happens if they are drawn together

Comment: Related: [In UEFA Champions League, how is it ensured that two teams from the same Country aren't drawn into the same group?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/14597)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually, because there are only two rules:
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_UEFA_Champions_League_knockout_phase))

1. Teams from the same group may not be drawn against each others.
2. Teams from the same association may not be drawn against each others.

Liverpool played PSG in the group stage and City is from the same association, that's why those match-ups are not possible in the next round.

This is done as follows:

1. All runners-up are placed in one bowl.
2. All group winners have an own bowl each.
3. When a runner-up is drawn an empty bowl will be filled with all possible group winners, eliminating the possibility to draw an ineligible opponent.
4. When there's no need to draw (e.g. one eligible opponent left) the match will be placed directly.
5. If the last match would become invalid the previous match is selected directly. This happened in the 2016 round of 16 draw.

A computer helps by showing any (in)eligible opponents when a runner-up is drawn.

Comment: But what would happen if PSG were drawn against LFC. What would the next step be. Would another ball be taken out of the pot until PSG have a suitable match and then LFC are put back in the pot for the next draw. What happens if PSG and LFC are the last two teams left in the draw in the round of 16, how does this all work.

Comment: @DANZERELLI I appened more details now.